# NetBeans Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 ошыбка cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, macos, cocos2d

Здравствуйте! Я использую NetBeans IDE & Cocos2dx (дома использую Ubuntu Linux 16.04 , и Windows 7) для собственных проектов. Все мои проекты компилируются и работает должным образом, в этих двух системах. В последнее время, на моей основной работе мне нужно использовать Cocos2dx (здесь я использую OS X El Capitan). Я хотел бы использовать одну и ту же IDE на всех системах. Но когда я скомпилировал базовый пример в NetBeans (еще пробовал СodeBlocks, CLion, QtCreator) на 99 процентах компиляции происходит ошибка, и я не знаю, как это исправить в NetBeans.
В XCode и з cocos консоли все компилируется и собирается должным образом, но мне хотелось бы использовать одну IDE во всех системах.

Текст ошибки:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FontUtils::_calculateTextAlignment(cocos2d::Device::TextAlign)", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Device::getTextureDataForText(char const*, cocos2d::FontDefinition const&, cocos2d::Device::TextAlign, int&, int&, bool&) in libcocos2dInternal.a(CCDevice-mac.mm.o)
  "FontUtils::_calculateParagraphStyle(bool, int)", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Device::getTextureDataForText(char const*, cocos2d::FontDefinition const&, cocos2d::Device::TextAlign, int&, int&, bool&) in libcocos2dInternal.a(CCDevice-mac.mm.o)
  "FontUtils::_calculateTextDrawStartWidth(cocos2d::Device::TextAlign, CGSize, CGSize)", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Device::getTextureDataForText(char const*, cocos2d::FontDefinition const&, cocos2d::Device::TextAlign, int&, int&, bool&) in libcocos2dInternal.a(CCDevice-mac.mm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/MyGame] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы выбрал Qt Creator, он будет лучшим выбором(для разработки под UNIX, по-моему лучше IDE вы не найдете). Внимательно смотрите на то, что устанавливается, обязательно нужно поставить галочку на компилятор(советую MinGW)